# Proof of for all integer $n \ge 2$, $n^3-n$ is divisible by 6 by mathematical induction.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

Prove the following statement by mathematical induction:
For all integer $n \ge 2$, $n^3-n$ is divisible by 6

My attempt:
[Proof]
 Let the given sentence p(n)
(1) $2^3-2$=6 is divisible by 6. p(2) is true.
(2) Suppose for all integer $k \ge 2$, p(k) is true. 
That is, mathematical hypothesis is $k^3-k$ is divisible by 6.

Then we must show that p(k+1) is true.

$(k+1)^3-(k+1) = (k^3 +3k^2+3k+1)-(k+1)$=$(k^3 -k)+(3k^2+3k)$

I have to get some multiple of 6 from $(3k^2+3k)$ to reach p(k+1) is true. How can I complete this proof?

Comment: $3k^2+3k=3k(k+1)$. But $k(k+1)$ is even. Then $3k^2+3k$ is multiple of 2 and 3.

Comment: $(3k^2 + 3k) = 3(k^2 + k)$.  Is $k^2 + k$ even, odd, or does it depend?  Hint:  it doesn't depend.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$3k^2+3k = 3k(k+1)$$

Either $k$ or $k+1$ is even, so this is divisible by $3\cdot 2 = 6$.

Answer (score 1):

Let's try this way- $n^3-n = n(n+1)(n-1)$

I make two statements - *There exists one multiple of three in any three consecutive natural numbers*

and *There exists atleast one even number in any three consecutive numbers*

If the above two statements make sense, Then, the given equation is divisible by $6$

Comment: This does not answer the question. The OP needed help with **mathematical induction**.

Answer (score 1):

If $k$ is odd then $3k^2 + 3k$ is even.

If $k$ is even then $3k^2 + 3k$ is even.